How can I multiple two spring boot web applications on same port with different endpoints?
I have two spring boot web applications. I want those applications to be deployed on same port with different endpoints, like

Application 1 - xx.xx.xx.xx:80/app1
Application 2 - xx.xx.xx.xx:80/app2

I am trying to deploy these applications using docker in AWS EC2. Please let me know how to do this.
Thank you!
When I tried to deploy two applications on same port, it failed.

Sounds like you want a reverse proxy. Something like this? https://serverfault.com/questions/1091572/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-subpath

You can't have two apps on a single machine listening on the same port. Can you put both endpoints in the same application?

Having two apps running on the same port on a single machine is impossible. However, you can run applications on each port and combine them using Nginx.
Example:

Application A (/app1) is running on 8080

Application B (/app2) is running on 8081

And the below Nginx Config might cover your case, I guess.
listen 80;

 location /app1 {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

 location /app2 {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }



